# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id (with Build Tools > 23.0.1)

Tags: android, android-fragments

Because of the new releases (or otherwise I can't compile Firebase or Google Play Services, I had to give up to my `buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'` and start using one greater than that one.

The problem I've got is that I'm getting this crash when I `startActivity` (so I suppose that Fragment goes to recycle):

```
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0f028c (com.pronuntiapp.debug.uat:id/root_frame) for fragment PeticionesFragment{f7650f6 #5 id=0x7f0f028c}
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1059)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.popFromBackStack(BackStackRecord.java:971)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackState(FragmentManager.java:1670)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManager.java:577)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5497)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

my `PeticionesFragment` is a fragment populated from a previous fragment (`RootPeticionesFragment`), which is in a ViewPager.

**RootPeticionesFragment.java**

```
public class RootPeticionesFragment extends BaseFragment {

    View view;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.root_fragment, container, false);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();

        transaction.replace(R.id.root_frame, new PeticionesFragment());

        try {
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return view;
    }

}
```

**root_fragment.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/root_frame" >

</FrameLayout>
```

and it's crashing because of this part on the FragmentManager

```
                            if (container == null && !f.mRestored) {
                                throwException(new IllegalArgumentException(
                                        "No view found for id 0x"
                                        + Integer.toHexString(f.mContainerId) + " ("
                                        + f.getResources().getResourceName(f.mContainerId)
                                        + ") for fragment " + f));
                            }
```

which wasn't existing on the previous buildTools.
I debugged the code, and `container` is null.

What's the magic trick to not making it crash? It's worked all the time.

Cheers!

Comment: Try to download latest google play services and sdk tools from sdk manager.amd use latest google play services and build tool in gradle.

Comment: Hi @PawneshwerGupta, why a newer version of Gradle should fix the problem? Could you please explain ?

Comment: not latest version of gradle, i said latest version of google play services.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?